# How to calculate the time difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i do the calculation to get the time difference. I have both the time of the server and the time of the client system in `isoDate` date format. Here are the output data i have :

Server time which is in UTC converted to local sytem timezone time :

`Tue May 22 2012 14:29:51 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Local System Time :

`Tue May 22 2012 14:31:51 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

I want to do the calculation in such a way that if the local system time is less then or greater then say 5 min (configurable value) ignoring the difference in seconds compared to what the server time is showing want to perform some task else another task. I dont know how to do the calculation because when it is midnight 12:01 am according to the server time then the date, hour and minute changes whereas if the local system is just 4 min behind how to determine the difference is not less then 5 min although the date changed. My main idea is to check everything to match date, time and check the difference. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getDateDiff(date1, date2) {
    var second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    date1 = new Date(date1).getTime();
    date2 = (date2 == 'now') ? new Date().getTime() : new Date(date2).getTime(); // now means current date
    var timediff = date2 - date1;
    if (isNaN(timediff)) return NaN;
    return Math.floor(timediff / minute);
}
```

**Use:**

```
getDateDiff(YOUR_SERVER_DATE, YOUR_CLIENT_DATE); // output will be in unit minute
```

or

```
getDateDiff(YOUR_SERVER_DATE, 'now'); // for current date
```